# What's a neater way to run bandit within python that doesn't involve shelling out

Tags: python, bandit-python

I'm using the following package: https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit to perform some static analysis on runtime. Currently I do the following:

```
subprocess.Popen(['bandit', '-r', full_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But I'm trying to move away from using subprocess.Popen, is it possible to natively call bandit in python? Something like

```
from bandit import ...
run_bandit(directory, recursive=True)
```

Comment: take a look at what the cli does and try to mimic the parts you need from that (https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/blob/master/bandit/cli/main.py)

Comment: It looks like you should be able to run bandit.cli.main.main() in Python, but I haven't tested it.  I think you would have to fake the command line arguments in sys.argv.